# Flagging bug reports as off-topic

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, scope

Today I came across a question reporting a bug of a SCSS-Lint where the software is not outputting the expected result. Someone pointed out in the comments that Stack Overflow is not a bug tracking site and referred the OP to the official site of SCSSLint to report the issue (and I agree).

AFAIK software bugs/limitation cannot be solved by the SO format, only acknowledged. So I have tried to mark the post as off-topic, however, the current options don't seem to address questions of bugs. What about adding another off-topic option for such questions?

[image: Current off-topic reasons]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While we do get pure bug reports from time to time, they're not common enough to justify yet another entry on the list of close reasons. It's perfectly fine to use a custom off topic reason and state something like

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be a bug report for a product, not a specific programming question.

As πάντα ῥεῖ points out, sometimes these questions about bugs aren't really intended as bug reports but are attempts to find workarounds. I've seen some great answers to questions like that. Questions that can be solved using code provided by people other than the authors of a product most likely aren't off topic here.

While it may seem easy to just add one more canned close reason, the more entries you add to the close vote dialog, the harder it becomes to parse when you vote to close. It's already pretty cumbersome, in my opinion.

Comment: So for those of us without close vote privileges, such as myself and the OP, should we use "Blatantly Off-Topic" for pure bug reports, or do you suggest a different reason? (Just to clarify)

Comment: @Kendra - Right, forgot the custom options don't apply to close flags. For those, I'd go with "blatantly off topic" if you think it is indeed unanswerable and let the reviewers apply the custom reason as needed.

Answer (score 2):

> AFAIK software bugs / limitation cannot be solved by the SO format, only acknowledged.

That's not completely true. There are questions about bugs of particular and popular programming tools (SCSS-Lint might be considered so), that have exact answers that confirm that there is a bug. And they are well achieved in the community, and considered helpful for future research.

Sample: [Is this C++11 regex error me or the compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060025/is-this-c11-regex-error-me-or-the-compiler)

Comment: well you have a point, tho sometimes you can't do anything until the creators of a certain tool update it for a fix

Comment: @Aziz _"you can't do anything until the creators of a certain tool update it"_ Well, isn't that an answer? Not every answer here needs to shortcut **solve** a naturally existing problem, does it? At least to know that, will get researchers for thinking about an appropriate workaround or looking for a newer version of the tool. That's helpful, isn't it?